# Update column value in SQL without user interaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to update my column value every day at 12 AM in a table without user interaction.

Example: I have a column `Status` with `Active` and `Expired` as its possible values.

Now everyday at 12 AM, another column `DateRegistered` is checked. If `DateRegistered` is less than the current date, then it will update `Status` to `A` (for `Active`), and to `E` (`Expired`) otherwise.

Is there any way I can do this in SQL Server 2014 without any user interaction?

Comment: Just write a stored procedure to do just that, and then schedule that stored procedure for execution at 12am every day, using the SQL Server Agent jobs

Comment: you should use trigger https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Can I execute trigger without user interaction? Such that it execute automatically without update,insert options?

Comment: I've been searching all this while for a solution but can't find one. Is there any other option which doesn't use SQL Server Agent jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Stored procedure` to do this and schedule the same in the SQL `Job` under `SQL Server Agent` to run at every day 12AM.

Please refer this `MSDN` link to do the same.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

[image]

Comment: I have been searching all this while for Sql Server Agent, but can't find it. When I try to install it for 2014. It says already installed. But I can't found it anywhere in Sql 2014. :(